# Implication of use <url-pattern> in a Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Someone have a simple explanation about the effects the value of tag `<url-pattern>` in my  **web.xml** file will have in a Spring application? I ever use `*.html` without problems, but if I change to `/` to a more wide scope, I can't reach any page from my application.

If I choose `/`, how should be my mapping value in my controller, and how I should link to my views in the JSP files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to understand what the `<url-pattern>` mappings are. They are described in the Servlet specification, [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) in chapter 12.

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’ and
>     the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

So `[/...]/*` is path mapping, anything prefixed with `*.` is extension mapping, and `/` is the default match.

The Servlet specification also explains in what order those are checked.

When a request arrives, the Servlet container goes through all your `url-pattern` elements to find a match and then calls the `service(..)` method of the corresponding `Servlet`. In our case, this is `DispatcherServlet`.

The `DispatcherServlet` then, typically, uses a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` bean to figure out which handler method is the best match to handle the request. Basically it determines which `@Controller` `@RequestMapping` method to dispatch to. [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) has a property called [`useSuffixPatternMatch`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseSuffixPatternMatch-boolean-) (which is `true` by default) which determines

> Whether to use suffix pattern match (".*") when matching patterns to
>   requests. If enabled a method mapped to "/users" also matches to
>   "/users.*".

So if your servlet is mapped to

```
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

and the handler method is mapped

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
```

then a request to `/context/test.html` will be handled by that method.

> If I choose `/`, how should be my mapping value in my controller, and
>   how I should link to my views in the JSP files?

There are a million answers to this. It depends. Just take note of all the information above and decide for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the outstanding answer, i can say practically nailed what I want. just  one more question, if I may: you said there's one million ways for the mapping value when / is used; i want a scheme where no html file is displayed in the project's url, and have multiple controllers in several levels. Do I could use something similar to your example (**@RequestMapping(value = "/test")**) to acomplish things like /test/one, /test/two, etc, where teste, one, two are all controllers?

Comment: @KleberMota You can. Map your servlet to the default mapping ``/``. Then all your `@RequestMapping` values can be considered relative to that. As long as you don't explicitly map anything with an `html` extension, you'll never see `html` in the browser.